# How to use PDO to fetch data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Below are details:
1. PDO connect class which have the function to connect with DB. Say PDO_connect class.
2. Logic class file say MyLogic file, MyLogic file include PDO_connect and another class in which functions are written say MyFunction Class.

Problem :
I am not able execute select query and fetch object using below query.
MyFunction Class have function :

```
function gCD($query_type,$connection_obj,$u_id,$c_id)
{
    if($query_type == 'SELECT')
    {
        $prepare_sql = $connection_obj->prepare("SELECT c_n from cs where u_id=:u_id and c_id=:c_id");
        $query_select_clients = $prepare_sql->execute(array(':u_id'=>$u_id,':c_id'=>$c_id));
        echo "\n".$prepare_sql->rowCount();
        exit; //This is also not working.
        $g_c_obj = $prepare_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        var_dump($g_c_obj);
      }
}
```

All arguments are passed from MyLogic File, connection and other details.
If I do this debugging it returns true:

```
var_dump($prepare_sql->execute(array(':u_id'=>$u_id,':c_id'=>$c_id)))
```

But neither `rowCount()` nor `fetch()` are giving any output. Your help is highly valuable.

Comment: Try to execute query on database from phpmyadmin. Does it return any values?

Comment: yes it is giving 2 rows as output when executed on DB.

Comment: You'll have to do some other tests of your own. Can you create a `php file` with only the connection and a code to select this value and bind the parameters? Also, what happens if you replace this query with values and run without the need to bind them?

Comment: You should also check the result of your call to `fetch`. Is that call successful? You can also check those calls in the MySQL general log. Are the parameters as you expect them to be?

Comment: From the manual for `PDOStatement::rowCount()`: "If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information was too long for a comment so I am typing this as an answer to help debug your case.

Test each case as you go through using PDO functionality. Each functionality like `prepare`, `execute` and `fetch` have a return value. Capture the return value, analyze it and act based on the return value. Substitute your information in appropriate places and see where your execution path stops.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xyz', 'user', 'pass');

gCD('SELECT', $db, 2, 2);

function gCD($query_type,$connection_obj,$u_id,$c_id)
{
    if($query_type == 'SELECT')
    {
        try
        {
            $prepare_sql = $connection_obj->prepare("SELECT c_n from cs where u_id=:u_id and c_id=:c_id");
            if ($prepare_sql === false)
            {
                echo "PDO prepare failed\n";
                return false;
            }
            $query_select_clients = $prepare_sql->execute(array(':u_id'=>$u_id,':c_id'=>$c_id));
            if ($query_select_clients === false)
            {
                echo "PDO execute failed\n";
                return false;
            }
            echo "\n".$prepare_sql->rowCount();
            $g_c_obj = $prepare_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            if ($g_c_obj === false)
            {
                echo "PDO fetch failed\n";
                return false;
            }
            var_dump($g_c_obj);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo 'Exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Not a select statement', "\n";
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```